# Vim cursor position after expanding html tag

Tags: vim, indentation

I most IDEs and modern text editors (Sublime Text 3) the cursor is correctly indented after inserting a newline in between an html tag (aka 'expanding" the tag):

Before:

```
<div>|</div>
```

After pressing CR:

```
<div>
    |
</div>
```

But in Vim, this is what I get:

```
<div>
|</div>
```

How can I get the same behaviour in Vim like in most other editors (see above)?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/othree/xml.vim

Comment: I'm having trouble answering this question here for some reason ( keep getting errors when submitting one).  I've pasted my would-be answer in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rson/7bd877744ac59bee5491).

Comment: @RandyMorris I had no problems posting it as an answer. Try posting it again?

Comment: @FDinoff no dice.  Thanks for trying it out though, I guess something is busted on either my computer or my account.

Comment: @FDinoff must have been my work machine. It worked from my phone.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RandyMorris Most likely the firewall then.

Comment: @Kent Thanks for your tip, but this plugin didn't help.

Comment: @DanielLang with this plugin, you type `<tag>>` (`>` twice), you will get what you are expecting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only *correct* behavior of `<CR>` in insert mode is to break the line at the cursor.

What you want is an *enhanced* behavior and you need to add something to your config to get it: a mapping, a short function or a full fledged plugin.

When I started to use vim, that behavior was actually one of the first things I added to my vimrc. I've changed it many times in the past but this mapping has been quite stable for a while:

```
inoremap <leader><CR> <CR><C-o>==<C-o>O
```

I've used `<leader><CR>` to keep the normal behavior of `<CR>`.

---

Here is a small function that seems to do what you want:

```
function! Expander()
  let line   = getline(".")
  let col    = col(".")
  let first  = line[col-2]
  let second = line[col-1]
  let third  = line[col]

  if first ==# ">"
    if second ==# "<" && third ==# "/"
      return "\<CR>\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"

    else
      return "\<CR>"

    endif

  else
    return "\<CR>"

  endif

endfunction

inoremap <expr> <CR> Expander()
```

Comment: Thank you very much - your solution works and I'll accept it as an answer. I would rather have liked to see a more automatic behaviour like I get it in Sublime Text or Textmate. I might investigate learning vimscript and extending Randy Morris solution below.

Comment: FWIW, I use SnipMate and Sparkup for writing HTML. You should consider those plugin: they will help you save **a lot** of typing.

Answer (score 3):

This little snippet will remap <kbd>Enter</kbd> in insert mode to test whether or not the cursor is between `>` and `<` and act accordingly if it is.  Depending on your indent settings the `\<Tab>` may need to be removed.

It will *not* play nice with other plugins that might be also be mapping the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key so be aware that there is probably more work to do if you want that compatibility.

```
function EnterOrIndentTag()
  let line = getline(".")
  let col = getpos(".")[2]
  let before = line[col-2]
  let after = line[col-1]

  if before == ">" && after == "<"
    return "\<Enter>\<C-o>O\<Tab>"
  endif
   return "\<Enter>"
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <Enter> EnterOrIndentTag()
```

I have only tested the simple cases (beginning of the line, end of the line, inside and outside of `><`), there are probably edge cases that this would not catch.

Comment: Thank you Randy. Your solution is very nice, but in fact I need something that plays nice with other plugins like matchIt. Your code got me onto thinking about writing such a function though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@RandyMorris and @romainl have posted good solutions for your exact problem.

There are some other possibilities you might be interested in if you are typing out these tags yourself: there's the [***ragtag.vim***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896) plugin for HTML/XML editing.

With *ragtag.vim* you type this to create your "before" situation (in insert mode):

```
div<C-X><Space>
```

To create your "after" situation you would instead type:

```
div<C-X><Enter>
```

So if you know beforehand that you are going to "expand" the tag, typing just the element name and the combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> is enough.

There are also other more advanced plugins to save keystrokes when editing HTML, such as [*ZenCoding.vim*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981) and [*Sparkup*](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, although I already had the ragtag-plugin installed and use it a lot for inserting ruby tags (so I know it works).

Answer (score 0):

Since no one have mentioned it I will. There is excellent plugin that does exactly that
[delemitmate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate)