# Vim - Css cursor position

Tags: css, vim

Following on from this question [HTML cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066591/461887)

How can i get the correct cursor position when pressing ENTER to expand css.

The commented section is my failed attempt at updating the function to work for css as well.

```
function! Expander()
  let line   = getline(".")
  let col    = col(".")
  let first  = line[col-2]
  let second = line[col-1]
  let third  = line[col

if first ==# ">"
    if second ==# "<" && third ==# "/"
      return "\<CR>\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"

    else
      return "\<CR>"

    endif
  "else if first ==# "{"
    "if second ==# "}"
      "return "\<CR>\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"

  else
    return "\<CR>"

  endif

endfunction
```

I am open to a solution with or without the function. plugins such as emmet and sparkup are great for creating html from abbreviated text but don't solve this simple problem.

I expect the cursor to be here on enter.

```
#SomeID {
        |
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended version of the function I proposed in the linked answer. It tries to expand `()`, `{}`, `[]` and `<tag></tag>`.

```
" the main function
function! SmartEnter()
  " beware of the cmdline window
  if &buftype == "nofile"
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  " get the character on the left of the cursor
  let previous = getline(".")[col(".")-2]

  " get the character on the right of the cursor
  let next     = getline(".")[col(".")-1]

  " do the right thing
  if previous ==# "{"
    return PairExpander(previous, "}", next)
  elseif previous ==# "["
    return PairExpander(previous, "]", next)
  elseif previous ==# "("
    return PairExpander(previous, ")", next)
  elseif previous ==# ">"
    return TagExpander(next)
  else
    return "\<CR>"
  endif
endfunction

" expands {}, (), []
function! PairExpander(left, right, next)
  let pair_position = searchpairpos(a:left, "", a:right, "Wn")
  if a:next !=# a:right && pair_position[0] == 0
    return "\<CR>" . a:right . "\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"
  elseif a:next !=# a:right && pair_position[0] != 0 && indent(pair_position[0]) != indent(".")
    return "\<CR>" . a:right . "\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"
  elseif a:next ==# a:right
    return "\<CR>\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"
  else
    return "\<CR>"
  endif
endfunction

" expands <tag></tag>
function! TagExpander(next)
  if a:next ==# "<" && getline(".")[col(".")] ==# "/"
    if getline(".")[searchpos("<", "bnW")[1]] ==# "/" || getline(".")[searchpos("<", "bnW")[1]] !=# getline(".")[col(".") + 1]
      return "\<CR>"
    else
      return "\<CR>\<C-o>==\<C-o>O"
    endif
  else
    return "\<CR>"
  endif
endfunction
```